# Identify whether traversing in browser history or on latest page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, history.js

Is there any way to identify if I have moved back to some older pages by using browser's back button or I'm standing on the latest page(on top of history stack).

---

Using History.js, JQuery 1.7

Comment: You'd have to ask the server. The current page would have no clue.

Comment: Isn't there any method from HTML5 history API that tells whether or not a forward traversal (using browser's forward button) may be possible. I'm wondering why this is not possible because the browser already has this information that it uses to activate/deactivate forward/back buttons.

Comment: The browser knows you have gone back, but it has no idea whether there is a new page on the server until it goes and asks. That's how HTTP works.

Comment: no perhaps you misunderstood my question, I meant when I went forward & came back using back button, so in that case the browser very well  knows that a forward is possible since it activated the forward button on browser.

Comment: Going forward will show you the page in the browser's cache, by default. You can manipulate the history object directly though:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

Comment: For securityreasons the browser will never let a webpage know what your current history is. There are no return values from `window.history.back()` nor `window.history.forward()`. This is to make sure that pages can not "sniff out" where you've been and use it for malignant purposes.